# Pan viewer window changes scale first time

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, c#

I have written a simple tool to pan a viewer window (if present) to the centre of the map view, which reduces the number of clicks required and mouse travel to *Pan Viewer to Map Location*, it works mostly as anticipated but if the scale of the map viewer is set to a round number (in this case 24000) the scale is expanded on the first use but not on 3rd or subsequent uses:
[image: Before running the code] Scale set before running.
[image: First time code is run] Scale after running first time.
[image: Second and subsequent] Scale for further instances.

The code:

```
IPoint CentreOfScreen = new PointClass();
IPoint CentreOfInset = new PointClass();

// derive the centre of the map from the active view extent
IEnvelope pMapExtent = ArcMap.Document.ActiveView.Extent;
CentreOfScreen.PutCoords((pMapExtent.XMax + pMapExtent.XMin) / 2,(pMapExtent.YMax + pMapExtent.YMin) / 2);

// get the application windows, could be of a few  
// types but we'll filter the one we want later
IApplicationWindows pAppWin = (IApplicationWindows)ArcMap.Application;
ISet pDatWindows = pAppWin.DataWindows;

// reset the enumeration and get the first object so that it's not null
// Leaving pDatWin unset will mean the loop will not progress
pDatWindows.Reset();
Object pDatWin = pDatWindows.Next();

while (pDatWin != null)
{
    if (pDatWin is IMapInsetWindow)
    {
        // this is the type of data window we want, not an overview window
        IMapInsetWindow pInsWin = (IMapInsetWindow)pDatWin;
        IMapInset pIns = pInsWin.MapInset;

        double pPreScale = 0;
        if (pIns.UsingZoomScale)
        {
            pPreScale = pIns.ZoomScale; // is set correctly 
        }

        // derive the centre of the map viewer from its visible bounds
        IEnvelope pExt = pIns.VisibleBounds;
        CentreOfInset.PutCoords((pExt.XMax + pExt.XMin) / 2, (pExt.YMax + pExt.YMin) / 2);

        // find how far to move the edges of the extent by finding the displacement
        // of the centre of screen to the centre of the map viewer
        double dX = CentreOfScreen.X - CentreOfInset.X;
        double dY = CentreOfScreen.Y - CentreOfInset.Y;

        // apply the offset to a new envelope
        IEnvelope pNewExt = new EnvelopeClass();
        pNewExt.PutCoords(pExt.XMin + dX,   pExt.YMin + dY,
                        pExt.XMax + dX, pExt.YMax + dY);

        // assert the new extent on the inset
        pIns.VisibleBounds = pNewExt;

        if (pIns.UsingZoomScale)
        {
            pIns.ZoomScale = pPreScale; // again set correctly
        }
        pInsWin.MapInset = pIns; // reset the inset window map inset

        // refresh and yield until the inset is redrawn
        pInsWin.Refresh();
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
    }
    pDatWin = pDatWindows.Next(); // go to the next data window
}
```

Reasserting the scale seems to have no effect; The math is fairly simple so it's unlikely I'm making a mistake there, if there were a mistake in the math I would expect the extent to keep growing on 2nd and subsequent iterations.

Has anyone who has worked with a viewer window in ArcObjects that can establish why the scale changes and knows how to keep the original scale?

Comment: Did you try using `PanStart`, `PanMoveTo`, `PanStop` on `IMapInsetWindow.ScreenDisplay` ?

Comment: Yes @KirkKuykendall there was no effect on the IMapInsetWindow, either the PanMoveTo coordinates are in *screen coordinates* or there was something wrong with the IPoint I passed; I abandoned that approach early and copied some very old code for *zoom2point* which, from my comments, had the same problem which I solved by then setting IMap.MapScale before IActiveView.Refresh(). IMap is not implemented by IMapInsetWindow so I can't do that. I also tried pExt.Expand(0.9,0.9,true), while it did reduce the extent every iteration after that reduced the extent further.

Comment: Before getting `pIns.VisibleBounds`, did you try calling `pIns.CalculateVisibleBounds()` ?

Comment: No luck there @KirkKuykendall, calling before IEnvelope pExt = pIns.VisibleBounds; changes the scale from 10k to ~330k but calling after pIns.ZoomScale = pPreScale; the scale becomes ~1.3 million, increasing to ~3 million on the second iteration.